# internet explorer 7 css issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, smarty

cart theme which uses smarty template engine. I am able to move the shoping cart links to above the top menu and it shows Ok with IE8 firefox etc. Hovewer IE7 make an empty space. How could I make IE7 happy. I added the necessary  style-sheets and tpl [files](https://www.office.com/). Main css files are style.css and stle.base.css.

---

IE8 no space
[image]
<sub>(source: [livefilestore.com](http://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pSVU-pq1r6P8Tuw7rjpEieN8wCpAoC2VsmpBYWg3hG6xje45EWF6xrFAEXd7PBzfsNvgkpHK0WGoOVynnWrJrXg/ie8.png?psid=1))</sub>

IE7 with space
[image]
<sub>(source: [livefilestore.com](http://7uil7a.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pvNHi8Zr3khcizQTV4TkL_sEQaJJKVh-JsiZntjHM4BbDKnE11mVFPf8Ug52P6_6klZM99ffApAV-EfNM4Fc3zmASjMggWaF0/ie7space.png?psid=1))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 doesn't render CSS well. Create a special CSS file for IE7 and include it in your HTML as follows:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

In ie7.css, modify the margins, padding, etc. until the two versions appear identical.

Comment: By doing just what I described.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is helpful, but in additional:

Add this in the `<head></head>` tags:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

Inside the ie7.css you add the element to it, e.g.

```
.cart-thingy {
    margin: -10px 0 0 0;
}
```

And so on.

This will certainly help as well:

[Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: It just added 10px above "car is empty" . Space is still there

Comment: I've edited the code, try the CSS code again, it should 'pull' up the thingy that will stop the space from showing - you can increase the -10px to a higher number to move it up more.